# Slow restore of database mysqldump

Tags: mysql

5GB database takes 15 minutes to restore. CPU is utilized 10% on one thread, iotop shows 20MB/s or less. Can't understand why it is so slow and does not use all HW resources?

Comment: It's executing individual DDL and INSERT statements and writing to disk. There is overhead there between parsing, execution, and disk write. 15 minutes fo 5gb doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: @Hanz, what are your machine's specs? Do you have SSD or HD? iotop showing 20 mb/s is too relative to provide a solid answer.

Comment: This is a question for DBAs, not for programmers.

Comment: Low CPU usage suggests to me that the CPU is waiting — likely it's waiting for I/O requests. You can consider getting faster storage. You could also increase MySQL `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_log_file_size`.

Comment: It's SSD and I don't see any iowait. CPU has 12 threads. innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_log_file_size are far bigger than the db size i'm trying to restore.

Comment: @JNevill, why it doesn't reach any hw limits? io or cpu?

Comment: Hope mysqldump was done with `--extended-insert` option (use multiple-row INSERT syntax that include several VALUES lists) on? Also, 5GB/15min=5.5MB/s. So 20MB/s is not bad. Maybe there are too many indexes in your schema and it slows down inserts. You can try to restore without indexes and re-create them afterwards.

Comment: Mydumper/Myloader is the right choice for this. Besides making a binary dump of the whole DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mydumper/Myloader is the right choice besides binary dump restore of the whole database (mariabackup).

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using `mysqlpump`. It is the "parallelized" version of `mysqldump`. This blog really divulges some of the more specific features, including how to specify parallel degree: https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2015/10/14/getting-started-with-mysqlpump-2/.

Comment: Parallel restoration tool won't speed it up because i have one big table there. It'll still be one thread per table. I'm frustrated with the fact that restoration does not reach hw limits. Why is that?

Comment: My question was about restore. mysqlpump is the same ONE THREAD restore as mysqldump

Comment: Hanz, I'm not sure why your one thread wasn't using more resources. mysqlpump has the capability to be running your one thread in parallel, so I recommend using that.